# how to ssh from a vm to another vm that is on a different host

Tags: linux, networking, centos, ssh, virtual-machines

I have 2 CentOS computer in the same local area network. Both computers have their own virtual machines running CentOS. I would like to ssh from the virtual machine of 1 host to the virtual machine of the other host. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 6):

ssh'ing to a VM is no different than ssh'ing to any other system on the network. Log into one of the VM's, and type:

ssh remote_username@remote_host

remote_host should be the hostname of the machine you want to connect to. You could even use simply the ip of the host you want to connect to.

[This guide](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-use-ssh-to-connect-to-a-remote-server-in-ubuntu) is pretty basic if you want to get some more info about ssh.

Answer (score -2):

ssh user234@192.168.10.20 or the hostname

more options like

port number
ssh -p 10245 root@box

listening socket on the destination (very cool)

ssh -g -L8022:another_ip:22 user@primary_ip

then in another shell you can ssh to another_ip through the primary_ip on port 8022

ssh -p 8022 user@primary_ip